# R dataframe format dates when some are prior to 1/1/1900

Tags: r, date

I am importing a CSV with a dates column, and some of the dates are prior to 1/1/1900. I am trying to create a column in my dataframe with the dates in a %m-%d-%Y type of format, but my efforts return empty cells. Below is an example. Thanks for any help.

```
id <- c(1,2,3)
dates <- c(44321, 1, "December 25, 1890")
df <- data.frame(id, dates)
View(df)
```

[image]

```
df$dates2 <- as.Date(df$dates, format = "%m-%d-%y")
View(df)
```

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

Comment: so some inputs are a number from 1900 and others are the full length date written out like your example?

Comment: If there were a consistent origin then both  `as.Date("2021-05-05") - 44321`
and `as.Date("1900-01-01") - 1` would equal it but they are different so there seems to be an error in the question.

Comment: The 44321 date in long form came from Excel; see Limey's comment below on this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mixture of formats you have makes things slightly awkward, but ...

```
library(lubridate)

as_date(
  ifelse(
    is.na(as.numeric(dates)), 
    mdy(dates), 
    dmy("01-Jan-1900") + days(as.numeric(dates)-1)
  )
)
[1] "2021-05-06" "1900-01-01" "1890-12-25"
```

which seems reasonable.

Are you sure about the conversion of `44321`? [Neither 1900 nor 2000 were leap years...]

The `as.numeric()` calls are required because `dates` is coerced to character because of the final entry in the vector.

Comment: Thanks I have not used lubridate before, I will try it out right now. I think 44321 = 5/5/2021, at least from Excel, so there may be an issue with this solution here?

Comment: Never rely on Excel!  From [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year_problem): "Microsoft Excel has, since its earliest versions, incorrectly considered 1900 to be a leap year", which would explain the inconsistency.